# Passing different set of variables to two different tasks in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook in which I am working on two different versions of logstash. I need to pass different set of variables to tasks in order to get two versions working. I used below but this does not seem to be working:

```yaml
- name: Downloading logstash 7.8.0
  get_url:
    url: "{{ artifactory_bin_url_7.8.0 }}/{{ archive_name_7.8.0 }}"
    dest: "{{ TEMP_DIR }}/{{ archive_name_7.8.0 }}"
  when: "{{ logstash_version }}" == "7.8.0"

- name: Downloading logstash 7.10.0
  get_url:
    url: "{{ artifactory_bin_url }}/{{ archive_name }}"
    dest: "{{ TEMP_DIR }}/{{ archive_name }}"
  when: "{{ logstash_version }}" == "7.10.0"
```

Note: I can't use two different var file as the name of file should remain constant all over the product.

Changes done so far:

```yaml
- name: print logstash version
  debug:
    msg: "Logstash version is {{ application_version }}"
  #command: echo "Logstash version is {{ application_version }}"
  register: version_result

- name: Downloading logstash 7.8.0
  get_url:
    url: "{{ artifactory_bin_url_7.8.0 }}/{{ archive_name_7.8.0 }}"
    dest: "{{ TEMP_DIR }}/{{ archive_name_7.8.0 }}"
  when: version_result.stdout == "7.8.0"
```

Comment: I don't get what you are doing in the edited version of your question... Why would you `register` a `debug` task result? Just do `when: "application_version == '7.8.0'"`

Comment: Thanks for the revert. But after using when: "{{ application_version }} == '7.8.0'" I get below error:                                                                                                                                         fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ application_version }} == '7.8.0'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ application_version }} == '7.8.0'): float object has no element

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that Ansible should warn on this, because

> The `when` clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when*</sup>

So, a more proper usage of `when` would be:

```yaml
when: "logstash_version == '7.10.0'"
```

Comment: what if logstash_version var is coming from vars/main.yml?

Comment: Also using this when: "logstash_version == '7.10.0'" skips the task

Comment: The source of your variable has no influence on how it will be used in a playbook. Have you tried `- debug: var=logstash_version` to confirm that what is in your variable is what you expect it to be?

Comment: so, I am using this now , but still it does not work:                                                                  - name: print logstash version
  debug:
    msg: "Logstash version is {{ application_version }}"
  #command: echo "Logstash version is {{ application_version }}"
  register: version_result

- name: Downloading logstash 7.8.0
  get_url:
    url: "{{ artifactory_bin_url_7.8.0 }}/{{ archive_name_7.8.0 }}"
    dest: "{{ TEMP_DIR }}/{{ archive_name_7.8.0 }}"
  when: version_result.stdout == "7.8.0"                                   ** ADDED LATEST CHANGES IN THE QUERY****